# Can react-loadable be used in create-react-app server-side?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, server-side-rendering, react-loadable

I am attempting to do some code-splitting in my create-react-app application that utilizes server side rendering.

I am utilizing 'react-loadable` to do the code-splitting: https://github.com/thejameskyle/react-loadable

As of now I simply have split my `Home.js` component away from the rest of my app, just to see if it works.  In development mode (read: not SSR), it's chunked off and works fine.

However, I can't get things to work on the server.  I'm following the guide on their Github page and am stuck because of the webpack changes needed.  In `create-react-app` applications, you don't have access to webpack as it's hidden away.

The error I receive when starting the server is:

```
return (0, _importInspector.report)(import('../components/home/Home'), {
                                                ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
at createScript (vm.js:80:10) ...
```

I'm pretty sure it's because I don't have webpack configured correctly as stated in the guide.

In the guide, it clearly states for SSR:

> First we need Webpack to tell us which bundles each module lives inside. For this there is the React Loadable Webpack plugin.
>
> Import the ReactLoadablePlugin from react-loadable/webpack and include it in your webpack config. Pass it a filename for where to store the JSON data about our bundles.

```
// webpack.config.js
import { ReactLoadablePlugin } from 'react-loadable/webpack';

export default {
    plugins: [
        new ReactLoadablePlugin({
            filename: './dist/react-loadable.json',
        }),
    ],
};
```

I don't think this is possible without ejecting.
Anyone have any idea if `react-loadable` can be used in a `create-react-app` server-side-rendered application?

Answer (score 2):

import these modules at the top of your server file

```
require('ignore-styles');
require('babel-polyfill')
require('babel-register')({
    ignore: [ /(node_modules)/ ],
    presets: ['es2015', 'react-app'],
    plugins: [
        'syntax-dynamic-import',
        'dynamic-import-node',
        'react-loadable/babel'
    ]
});
```

Comment: Nice! The problem is that "dynamic-import-node" will make import() working on server but will cancel code splitting for browser. So we need to enable it for server only (DON'T add it to .babelrc) and this is a perfect place to do that. This answer should be accepted.

Comment: i have the same question but instead i'm using loadable/components and i get the feeling that it's not splitting correctly because of performance issues.